# node.js - how to install a single dependency globally?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

My package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "tets",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-less": "^3.0.3",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "karma": "^0.12.0",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.2.0",
    "mocha": "^2.2.5"
  }
}
```

To install this locally I would run `npm install` and to install all dependencies globally I would run `npm install -g`.  I only want to install gulp globally, though.  Is there any way to accomplish this?

As a caveat, I've integrated a gulpfile into a .NET project and have it running via a post-build event.  As a pre-build event, I'm executing `npm install` to ensure everything is setup correctly.  My hope is that any code to install only gulp globally can be added to the package.json file so I can keep my pre-build event to just `npm install`.  Unless adding `npm install gulp -g` to my pre-build event is acceptable...

Comment: You can do "npm install -g gulp", anything wrong with that?

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat: Added a caveat to my question.

Comment: I think you don't actually need to do this. Since you did `npm install`, the executable files will be in `node_modules/.bin`, you can add to your PATH variable and then gulp executable will be accessible. Though I'm not sure how you can do this on windows...

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat: The problem is my post-build event is `gulp styles scripts` and gulp is not globally accessible given the current `npm install`.  I'd prefer not to make other developers add gulp to their PATH variable if I don't have to.

Comment: I meant you can change the PATH in the script. You can also do this: `node_modules/.bin/gulp styles scripts`.

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat: Great idea.  In .NET, you have to quality the relative path a little more, but this works: `"$(SolutionDir)\Gorman.Abe.Web\node_modules\.bin\gulp" styles scripts`

Comment: FWIW `npm` supports the `postinstall` script event which you could leverage to run a script *after* npm has finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So @FaridNouriNeshat pointed me to a solution where gulp is accessed locally which is probably the most appropriate thing to do rather than globally install it into someone's machine.  In my case, I altered my post-build event in my .NET app to point to the local install of gulp rather than a global install.

```
"$(SolutionDir)\Gorman.Abe.Web\node_modules\.bin\gulp" styles scripts
```